# How to remove an attribute from testing in XMLUnit in Java?

Tags: java, xml, domdocument, cucumber-junit, xmlunit

I wanted to skip two attributes from my acceptance test.So I added following part to remove that two attributes.This is given me a error:
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff
[different] Expected number of element attributes '2' but was '1'

Part of XML file:

```
<a:content schemaVS="1"
a:schemaLocate="http://www.ContentXML.xsd"
whiteSpaceMode="preserve">
<section type="Chapter" id="drd121">
    <p type="H1">This is H1.</p>
</section>
```

Part of Java implementation:

```
public Document removeIgnoredCxmlNodes(Document resultDocument) {

Element contentElement=(Element) resultDocument.getElementsByTagName("a:content").item(0);
contentElement.removeAttribute("schemaVS");
contentElement.removeAttribute("a:schemaLocate");
return resultDocument;
```

}

```
public void cxmlShouldBeProduced(String location) throws Throwable {
try {
    Document expectedDocument = parseDocument(RESOURCES_DIR_PATH.resolve(location));
    Document resultDocument = removeIgnoredCxmlNodes(parseDocument(resultCxmlPath));
    assertXMLEqual(expectedDocument, resultDocument);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you print the two documents to xml? Apparently XMLUnit feels they are different. This might be true, and if that is acceptable, use a `DifferenceListener` as shown below by @jsheeran.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of using the default implementation of `DifferenceListener`. To specify that a comparison should ignore a particular type of difference, you need to provide your own implementation.

The following example is for XMLUnit 1. I haven't yet used 2, but from what I understand the solution would be much the same.

```
public class DifferenceListenerImpl implements DifferenceListener {
  @Override
  public int differenceFound(Difference d) {
    if (d.getId() == DifferenceConstants.ELEMENT_NUM_ATTRIBUTES_ID) {
      return RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_SIMILAR;
    }
    // handle other difference types here
  }

  @Override
  public void skippedComparison(Node control, Node test) {
    // not needed
  }
}
```

Comment: is this an abstract class?

Comment: `DifferenceListener` is an interface in XMLUnit 1; its equivalent in 2 is `DifferenceEvaluator`. The implementation is a concrete class.

Comment: When I am creating the DifferenceListener class it is given me an error .Eclipse suggests to convert this into abstract method  or add following method public void skippedComparison(Node arg0, Node arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: Implement the method and leave it blank. It's not needed for this purpose.

Comment: I implemented DifferenceListener to existing class and and put the solution code their..Is it the correct way to do?

Answer (score 2):

For XMLUnit 2.x you wouldn't use `DifferenceEvaluator` but an "attribute filter" like in

```
DiffBuilder b = DiffBuilder.compare(some-onput)
    .withTest(some-test)
    .withAttributeFilter(a -> {
        QName attrName = Nodes.getQName(a);
        return !a.equals(new QName("schemaVS"))
            && !a.equals(new QName(schema-uri-of-a, "schemaLocate"));
    })
    ...
```

Comment: I have configured xmlunit-1.6.jar in my project ,but DiffBuilder can not be resolved and I used this body within 'removeIgnoredCxmlNodes' method mentioned in the question.Am I correct here?

Comment: There is no `DiffBuilder` in XMLUnit 1.6,  that's why I said "in XMLUnit 2.x". If you are forced to stick with the old 1.6 then something like @jsheeran's answer is what you need to do.